# If $Q(P(x), x)$ is the zero polynomial, then $Q(x, y) = (y - P(x))A(x, y)$ for some $A$

Tags: polynomials

Let $Q(x, y)$ be a bivariate polynomial over some field $\mathbb{F}$, and $P(x)$ a univariate polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$ such that $Q(P(x), x) = 0$ for every $x$.

Show that then,  $Q(x, y) = (y - P(x))A(x, y)$ for some polynomial $A(x, y)$.

This is a self-exercice from Arora & Barak "Computational complexity", Chapter 19.   I am stuck.

[EDIT : this might be a mistake in the statement.  See comments.]

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, take $Q(x,y)=x-y^2$ and $P(x)=x^2$. Then $Q(P(x),x)=x^2-x^2=0$ but $Q$ is irreducible.

Comment: Hmm that sounds right.  Would you care to look at the problem statement from the book ?  It's Exercice 19.16 at http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=2D058C551DBB88D5CBD5B5F884F6C5DB?doi=10.1.1.297.6224&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=367.  Did I miss something ?

Comment: Actually, it is strange. What do you mean with bivariate and univariate? For what I read on Wolfram MathWorld they are just polynomial in two, resp. one, variables.. I am still convinced of my first comment and so I am tempted to say that maybe the statement is incomplete or the definition of bivariate is another one..

Comment: Or sometimes the solution is easier and there was just a typo: the claim should be $Q(x,y)=(x-P(y))A(x,y)$. The exercise requires nothing about the triviality of $A$ and hence my first comment fits perfectly in this case.

Comment: You may be right...I don't know really !  At least, your statement works with the counter-example, and I can't find any other.  I still can't prove it though, so if you have a proof, I'm interested :)

Comment: Well, it seems to me quite intuitive and clear now. By the way, a geometric way to justify it is to put $V=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{F}\,|\,Q(a,b)=0\}$ and $V'=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{F}\,|\,Q'(a,b)=0\}$ where $Q'(x,y)=x-P(y)$. The hypothesis reads $V'\subset V$ and hence $Q$ factorises through $Q'$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations!  It all makes sense now.

Comment: Your welcome! Happy to be helpful.

Comment: @ManuelLafond Do you know a proof for this claim?

Comment: @TrueTopologist Hm...I did understand Cla's last comment at the time, 2 years ago.  But now I'm not sure.  The argument is that whenever $x - P(y) = 0$, we have $Q(x, y) = 0$ (using the initial hypothesis on $Q$).  And therefore, $Q$ must factorize through $x - P(y)$.  I'm just not sure about the last "therefore" - I don't remember why that works.  Maybe you'll have an idea :)